# How to interpret output position values of Geometry node

Tags: node-editor, osl

I have a simple sphere with a material. And I want to know how understand information the Geometry node gives. I printed this information through OSL shader. Can somebody please explain to me why the position output is roughly (10 10 10), while the object world location is (0 0 30)?

[image]

```
shader Inspector(float input=0,output color debug=0)
{
  debug = input;
  printf("\n");
  printf("%f" , debug );
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How big is your sphere?  Is the sphere's origin at its center? Where's the file that shows that problem? Which version of blender are you using? Gosh, so many questions... This is because the Position gives exactly the world coordinates of the point being sampled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Position output of the geometry node yields the current shading point (on the surface of your sphere) in World Space. It is the equivalent of the global variable **P** in OSL.

A lot of the outputs are equvalent to OSL Globals:

**Position**: point **P** Position of the point you are shading.

**Incoming**: The *negative* of OSL's vector **I**: The incident ray direction, pointing from the viewing position to the shading position **P**.

**Normal**: normal **N** The surface “Shading” normal of the surface at **P**.

**True Normal**: normal **Ng** The true surface normal at **P**.(before bump mapping, etc.)

**Parametric**: float **u**, **v** The 2D parametric coordinates of **P**, as defined for the current object.

The rest as per [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/geometry.html)

Your interpretation of `point` as `float` seems to have unpredictable results..

I've found you have to use the printed variable in some way to prevent the print from being optimized? away.

```
shader Inspector(
point input = 0.0,
output color debug = 0.0
)
{
    debug = input;
    //pointless calculation to prevent printf being optimized away
    debug[0] = pow(debug[0],1);
    printf("%f \n",debug);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be working with vector type as well if we add a pointless calculation. I'm wondering why there is no such optimization with float interpretation.

Comment: @OleksiyPlotnyts'kyy maybe because, as Secrop points out, the cast from `point` to `float` involves a calculation.. the cast between triples just involves passing the components on, unaltered.

Answer (score 2):

You're turning a vector into a float. So float=(v[0]+v[1]+v[2])/3.

this will give the correct result:

```
shader Inspector(float xcomp=0, float ycomp=0, float zcomp=0, output color debug=0)
{
  debug = (xcomp+ycomp+zcomp)/3;
  printf("\n");
  printf("%f,%f,%f >> %f" , xcomp, ycomp, zcomp, debug);
}
```

Use the SeparateXYZ and connect each components to the script.

Comment: It doesn't give any output with vector type now.

Comment: Ahh.. so _that's_ what the cast from `point` to `float` is doing..I  couldn't work it out...

Comment: @OleksiyPlotnyts'kyy, ohh, osl optimizations.. I'm changing the script ;)